# WooCommerce countr total of product inside a cat and its subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using the below code will output `0` this category has a sub-category and when I use that sub-categories' ID it returns `17`.

What I am trying to do is get the total products of the parent category which includes the count of subcategories too.

```
$term = get_term( 16, 'product_cat' ); // <--- tested in my system with this ID
echo 'Product Category: '. $term->name. ' - Count: '. $term->count;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = "SELECT sum(count) AS total FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent = '16'";
$r = $wpdb->get_results($q);
$total = $r[0]->total;
```